# Inserting Link inside Mailto body

Tags: html, model-view-controller, outlook, mailto

I need to add some URLS to pdfs inside my email body

Outlook can create clickable (ctrl+right click) links inside the body. The problem is that if I have spaces in the pdf name the URL breaks.

Here is the html generated in my app. The problem is only with the Spaces inside url. I was trying to replace URLs spaces server side with '%20' but this also didn't help.

```
<a href="mailto:;somemail@gmail.com;?Subject=SomeSubject&amp;body=http://someUrl/File%20name%202015-05-21%2011-21-08.pdf%0D%0A%0D%0A" title="title" class="btn">Send email</a>
```

Clickable URL will break on the first space:

```
http://someUrl/File...
```

Is there anyway to encode urls so outlook will create proper links inside the body ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have spaces in URLs so you must encode the space in the filename in order to create a URL to the file.

`mailto:` URLs are URLs so an encoded space will be converted back to a regular space when it is parsed. When inserting one URL into an other, you must encode all the special characters in the nested URL (i.e. you need to convert the `%` characters to `%25`).

Comment: but even if I encode the url ie. using HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode and all the characters get encoded (space to %20 etc) when I click the link in html the URLs in Outlook get decoded and I only get the partial link.

Comment: @MateuszMigała — So you've encoded the spaces in the filename you want to put in the HTTP URL. You haven't encoded the % signs in the URL you want to put in the mailto URL. (Which is rather the point of this answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way to achieve this is to call  js `encodeUrl()` twice

```
encodeUrl(encodeUrl(url))
```